# Getting an error while running a python script involving java

Tags: java, python, runtime-error

I am using the library pytimeextractor which requires Java.
It shows an error while running it.

> SystemError: Error calling dlopen(b'/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib': b'dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib, 10): image not found'

When I first imported and ran it, it gave an error `KeyError: JAVA_HOME`. I installed maven and setup the JAVA HOME. Now `echo $JAVA_HOME` shows appropriate results. But I ended up getting this new error. I tried searching around for a solution for this. Unfortunately, I haven't been successful. Any help would be appreciated.

The first time I ran it, it only showed the JAVA_HOME KeyError and doing `echo $JAVA_HOME` used to give a blank line. However researching the problem a bit, I was able to set up the PATH and was able to solve that problem. However, I have no idea what does this new error mean.

Comment: What's under your `JAVA_HOME` variable? Maybe it points to the wrong directory (eg. goest to /bin instead of the parent of it)

Comment: @itwasntme ```JAVA_HOME``` is set to ```/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home ```
My java version is 12.0.2 .

Comment: shouldn't it be set just to `.....jdk-12.0.2.jdk/`? I've checked few of installed java versions I have and there was not `Contents/Home` directories under main directory

Comment: I followed a YouTube video on setting up the ```JAVA_HOME``` to ```PATH```. I have never used Java till date. And the video showed ```Contents/Home```.
Also i read this page https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Check the real path on of your java installation. Then use this path to set `JAVA_HOME`, the home in most of the cases should be set to the root directory of installed JRE/JDK.

Comment: How to check the 'real' path of the java installation?

Comment: Test if your JAVA_HOME is pointing to the correctly path, open a terminal and try the following command: ```java -version``` it should print the version of installed JRE. If it prints a command not found error your variable is set incorrectly.

Comment: @Paschoal It shows 12.0.2

Comment: From my research, it seems like a bug/behavior of the jnius library, used to interface python with java, trying to search the Java in the wrong folders when using a different JRE than it expects. Take a look at the this [issue](https://github.com/dlt-rilmta/emtsv/issues/1) at GitHub, is the same error, maybe it can give you some direction to solve the problem.